# Есть ли в C++ возможность получить внутри объекта его имя в виде строки?

Tags: c++

Есть следующий код:

```
#define VAR_NAME(Var) (#Var)

#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

struct cfg_pair{
    std::string marker, value;
    cfg_pair(const char * name): marker("\r\n"+std::string(name)+"=") {}
    bool Init(std::string &buffer){
        if( marker.empty() ) return false;
        int beg = buffer.find(marker);
        if( beg < 0 ) return false;
        beg += marker.size();
        int end = buffer.find("\r\n",beg);
        if( end < 0 ) end = buffer.size();
        value = buffer.substr(beg,end-beg);
        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cfg_pair test(VAR_NAME(test));

    printf("%s\n",test.marker.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы поле `marker` инициализаровалось именем созданного объекта `cfg_pair` без передачи каких-либо аргументов в конструктор? То есть просто "изнутри" как-то брать имя объекта (в данном случае - `test`)?

Comment: Такое понятие, как "имя объекта" в языке отсутствует. У переменной во время компиляции есть идентификатор, но во время исполнения программы он уже недоступен.

Comment: Нет, так сделать нельзя. Передавать имя снаружи вручную, как в вашем примере - единственный способ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имя типа объекта узнать можно через [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) : typeid(cfg_pair).name(). Имя объекта, как уже заметили в комментариях, после компиляции пропадёт. Нет средств языка, позволяющих анализировать имя экземпляра переменной (к тому же от этого нет особой пользы).

Можно сделать примерно такой функционал с помощью макросов препроцессора, но зачем?

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: Это как это? Автор вопроса хотел имя объекта (в примере - `test`). А `typeid(cfg_pair).name()` выдаст зашифрованное имя класса `cfg_pair`. То есть это совсем не то.

Comment: @AnT, понял, что то, что мне надо, сделать не выйдет, а typeid - да, это не то, я проверил